# penalty game in xna, how do I just count 1 goal and then let time for a goal message?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I am programming a penalty shoout game in xna, my question is how do I count just 1 goal and then let time for a goal message??,

I already solve the collison between the goalkeeper, goal and the goal area, and I keep and score but when the ball touched the goal area, the score always increment when the ball touched the goal area, how do I just count 1 goal and then display a goal message??

this is what I have so far, I think about a delay but its not working, please help I am stucked in this

```
 if (_gameState == GameState.Playing)
         {

             if (CollideGoalArea())
             {
                 if (CollideGoalKeeper())
                 {
                     _messageToDisplay = "Goalie defends the goal!";
                     this.Window.Title = "Missed!";
                     _gameState = GameState.Message;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     score++;
                     _messageToDisplay = "GOAL!";

                     this.Window.Title = "Goal!";

                     _gameState = GameState.Message;
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 _messageToDisplay = "You missed the goal.";
                 _gameState = GameState.Message;
             }



         }
         else if (_gameState == GameState.Message)
         {

             if (Mouse.GetState().RightButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
             { // right click to continue playing
                 _gameState = GameState.Playing;
                 balonpos.X = 300;
                 balonpos.Y = 350;

             }

         }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is happening because your code increments `score` any time it detects that ball is inside the goal. Since (by default) `Update` is called 60 times per second, if your ball is inside the goal score will get incremented by 60 every second.

You could rewrite your code so that your game has 2 states: Displaying a message state and playing state:

```
enum GameState
{
    Playing,
    Message
}

GameState _gameState = GameState.Playing;

String _messageToDisplay = "";
int _score = 0;

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if(_gameState == GameState.Playing)
    {
        if(CollideGoalArea())
        {
            if(CollideGoalkeeper())
            {
                _messageToDisplay = "Goalie defends the goal!";
                _gameState = GameState.Message;
            }
            else
            {
                _messageToDisplay = "GOAL!";
                score++;
                _gameState = GameState.Message;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _messageToDisplay = "You missed the goal.";
            _gameState = GameState.Message;
        }
    }
    else if(_gameState == GameState.Message)
    {
        if(Mouse.GetState().RightButton == ButtonState.Pressed) // right click to continue playing
             _gameState = GameState.Playing;

        //you should also reset your ball position here
    }
}
```

This way, whenever ball enters the goal area, it will either be a score, miss or hit on the goalkeeper. The game will then instantly change state so that those conditions aren't checked again until you right click with your mouse.

You could also put your input detection logic and ball and goalie position update logic inside these if's (you might not want for the player to be able to shoot another ball while the message is being displayed).

Comment: enum GameState is declared after the class right?, thanks for answering

Comment: you could declare the enum inside the class. This way other classes will not see it, as it does not concern them. If you want other classes to see this enum, declare it public.

Comment: I paste if(_gameState == GameState.Playing){}ese{} and I get Only assigment, call, increment, decrement, and new object object expressions can be used as a statement, I dont know why??

Comment: Check in which line this error appears, then look at that line and see if anything is wrong.

Comment: thanks for answering, but I still dont understand if I click left the mouse, my ball moves to that postion, the I click right mouse and my score increment like 3 times, and so on, how do I reset my ball?

Comment: You should set your ball position to the starting position.

Comment: I set  the ball postion like this:    balonpos = new Vector2(200, 200); in the inner if like you say, but the ball is drawn in another area and the click does not work, Idont know what I am doing wrong

Comment: I set  the ball postion like this:    balonpos = new Vector2(200, 200); in the inner if like you say, but the ball seems to be drawn but does not return to the initial state like a blurry drawn

Comment: Could you add an edit to your question, and paste the update code you have so far there.

Comment: please help me I am so stuck in this parte

Comment: Okay, so what exactly happens now when you click your right mouse (after the message is displayed)? You're setting it to 300, 350 - is this the starting position?

Comment: I click the mouse and It increments the score after like 3 clicks o more, and yes that Its the position of the ball

Comment: help me please I trying to increment the score just a click but It increments every 4 or five clicks